# color box that ignore mutated vowel

Tags: colorbox

Can someone help defining a new command?

I have the following to create a colored box around the content that is written in all caps:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\sect}[1]{
    \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}\\% Section title
}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\sect{Hallö}

\sect{Hallo}
\end{document}
```

However, the use of mutated vowels in German makes it look rather unpleasant, since the box becomes higher and the text is no longer centered. Just centering the text within the box is not a solution because boxes shall all be the same height, regardless of the content.

I tried to use `\makebox`but failed

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the depth the difference in height between “O” and “Ö”.

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\UCstrut}{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{O}%
  \settoheight{\dimen2}{Ö}%
  \vrule width 0pt height \dimen2 depth \dimexpr\dimen2-\dimen0\relax
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{%
  \colorbox{black}{\color{white}\bfseries\UCstrut\MakeUppercase{#1}}% Section title
}

\begin{document}

\sect{Hallö} \sect{Hallo}

\end{document}
```

[image]